# ¿Como puedo lanzar una excepción cuando se digite un string en una variable que debe tener un dato entero

Tags: java, bucles, excepciones

Deseo lanzar una excepcion para cuando por error se digite una  o mas letras en la
variable opcion la cual debe guardar  un dato entero, asi que de esa manera entre al swicth y 
que repita el codigo hasta que se digite correctamente

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Excepcion {
        int opcion;
        String dato;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        ListaCircularD2Enlazada listaPeliculas = new ListaCircularD2Enlazada();
        do {
            System.out.println("------------Lista circular d2 enlazada------------");
            System.out.println("1.Insertar elemento al inicio.");
            System.out.println("2.Insertar elemento al final.");
     //AQUI
            System.out.print("Digite una opción: ");
            opcion = sc.nextInt();
            switch (opcion) {

                case 1:
                    System.out.print("Digite el dato que desea ingresar: ");
                    dato = sc.next();
                    listaPeliculas.insertarAlComienzo(dato);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.print("Digite el dato que desea ingresar: ");
                    dato = sc.next();
                    listaPeliculas.insertarAlFinal(dato);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }while(opcion!=0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Necesitas que se haga de esa forma, o el punto es validar que el ingreso sea un entero.

Comment: como dices validar que el ingreso sea un entero, pero que a su vez me repita el mensaje de salida para poder ingresarlo hasta que sea correcto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambia este código:

```
opcion = sc.nextInt();
```

Por este:

```
        String n;
        // se lee la entrada como un string
        n = sc.nextLine();
        // se entra en un bucle mientras la entrada contenga algún caracter que
       // no sea un digito
        while(n.chars().anyMatch(c -> !Character.isDigit(c))){
            //si contiene un caracter que no es digito se pide de nuevo la entrada
            System.out.print("Digite una opción: ");
            n = sc.nextLine();
        }
        //si todos son digitos se convierte a int
        opcion = Integer.parseInt(n);
```